# React-TypeScript - Property 'then' does not exist on type '(dispatch: Dispatch<AnyAction>) => Promise<void>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux-toolkit for redux state management. Here is the code showing error

```
import * as actions from "../../../_redux/entities/entitiesActions";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { strict } from "assert";


const dispatch = useDispatch();

const deleteEntity = () => {
    // server request for deleting device by id
    dispatch(actions.deleteEntity(id)).then(() => {    //Error on this line
      // refresh list after deletion
      dispatch(actions.fetchEntities(entitiesUIProps.queryParams));
    });
  };
```

And entitiesActions.ts is here

```
//EntitiesActions.ts
const {actions} = entitesSlice;

export const fetchEntites = (queryParams:any) => (dispatch:Dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actions.startCall({ callType: callTypes.list }));
  return requestFromServer
    .findEntites(queryParams)
    .then(response => {
      const { totalCount, entities } = response.data;
      dispatch(actions.entitesFetched({ totalCount, entities }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      error.clientMessage = "Can't find entites";
      dispatch(actions.catchError({ error, callType: callTypes.list }));
    });
};

export const deleteEntity = (id:string) => (dispatch:Dispatch) => {
    dispatch(actions.startCall({ callType: callTypes.action }));
    return requestFromServer
      .deleteEntity(id)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(actions.deviceDeleted({ id }));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        error.clientMessage = "Can't delete device";
        dispatch(actions.catchError({ error, callType: callTypes.action }));
      });
  };
```

I don't know how to resolve this error. Please help!
Thanks!

**Edit:**

If I removed `then` block from outer dispatch, the error goes away but I'm afraid this will cause the nested dispatch to fire before outer dispatch execution finishes?

```
const deleteEntity = () => {
    // server request for deleting device by id
    dispatch(actions.deleteEntity(id));//.then(() => {    //Error goes away
      // refresh list after deletion
      dispatch(actions.fetchEntities(entitiesUIProps.queryParams));
    //});
  };
```

Comment: Are you using `@reduxjs/toolkit`or just plain redux?

Comment: using @reduxjs/toolkit

Answer (score 3):

`dispatch` function should be synchronous, so it can't be await-ed. To make it returning a Promise when using Redux Toolkit you can use

```
  const useThunkDispatch = () => useDispatch<typeof store.dispatch>()
  const dispatch = useThunkDispatch()
```

Where store is created by `configureStore` of `@reduxjs/toolkit`.

> If I removed then block from outer dispatch, the error goes away but
> I'm afraid this will cause the nested dispatch to fire before outer
> dispatch execution finishes?

That's correct.